# Testing a promise object which contains a nested callback

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have the below function which calls a promise object

```
export const project_list = function(data,res){
  return db.any(queries.ProjectList)
    .then(function(results){
      let newResults = project_list_cleaner(results)
      res(null,newResults)
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      res(err)
    })
}
```

I'm trying to test the function like the below

```
  it('should retrieve a list',function(){
    return expect(project_list(data,res)).to.eventually.be.false
  })
```

this raised an error because the promise object doesnt actually return anything. it exectes the `res` callback.

is there anyway to test whether the promise object executes the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the function above returns a Promise does not matter for it's signature. The fact that you are passing a callback to it makes the Promise thing not usable.

## Solution 1: refactor your function

Make your function return a Promise and that's it. No callback involved.

```
export const project_list = function(data){
  return db.any(queries.ProjectList)
    .then(function(results){
      return project_list_cleaner(results)
    });
}
```

The test will then be:

```
it('should retrieve a list',function(){
  return expect(project_list(data)).to.eventually.be.false
})
```

## Solution 2: ignore the Promise

In this solution you don't refactor the function (but you really should!) and work as Promises never existed.

```
it('should retrieve a list',function(done){
  project_list(data, function(err, result){
    // put your assertions here
    done();
  });
})
```

Comment: So would a solution to this be that i have a higher order function calling the project_list function. The higher order function would call res based on project_list resolving or throwing?

Comment: Yes. If you can use Promises I'd say push the callback as high and you can and maintain the control of the async workflow with Promises if you can.

Comment: Made a higher order function to handle `res` . thanks

Comment: Thank you for the refractoring! Saved my day